# sorting a file?

Tags: python

I need to read a existing file that i wrote using a empty list for users raw_input. Not exactly sure on how I sort the file after reading. After sorting, i need to save it under a different file name and print.
This is what I have so far:

```
Names=[]

while 1:

    Input = raw_input("Enter a name or press 'v' to quit:")
    if Input == "v":
        break
    Names.append(Input)


raw_input ('Press Enter to write each of the names to a file named NAMES.')
text_file= open ("NAMES.txt", "w")
text_file.writelines(Names)
text_file.close()

raw_input('Press Enter to Read file into a sorted list.')


text_file = open("NAMES.txt", "r")
names = text_file.readlines()
text_file.close()
```

^This is where I need to sort and save under different file name and print. STUCK!

Comment: Do you know how to sort? Do you know how to write to a file?

Comment: [Here is a decent-looking overview of sorting mechanisms in Python](http://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting/) -- it might be too much too quickly -- but stick to the simple end of the spectrum, and you won't go too far wrong.

Comment: You don't sort the file, you sort the data structure in which you put the file's data. Programming requires precise wording. You should change the title.

Answer (score 0):

you can just sort the list of names .... `names.sort()`

```
>>> names=["John","Angel","Luis"]
>>> names.sort()
>>> names
['Angel', 'John', 'Luis']
```

**Edit: comment answer**

`writelines` [doesn't add line separators](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#file.writelines) therefore
when you do `text_file.writelines(Names)` you are writing just one line.

To write line separators you can do ...

`text_file.writelines(map(lambda x: x+'\n',Names))`

or simply append `\n` at the end of each name ...

`Names.append(Input+'\n')`

Comment: yes, but when i try to sort it comes back the same. Here, if I input a,c,d,b in the raw_input it comes back as ['acdb']

Comment: I have just edited my question, see the source of your error in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
names.sort()
```

http://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting/

Answer (score 0):

This is probably homework, so i'll give you some hints.

You should take a look at the python [**`docs`**](http://docs.python.org/howto/sorting.html) for sorting.

Using the .sort() method for a list will alter the list and give no return value.

```
>>> a = ['2','1']
>>> a
['2', '1']
>>> a.sort()
>>> a
['1', '2']
```

Using sorted() on a list, will return the list sorted, and not alter the original list:

```
>>> a = ['2','1']
>>> sorted(a)
['1', '2']
>>> a
['2', '1']
>>>
```

As far as reading in the file that you wrote, you probably want to strip the endline characters:

```
names = [ line.strip() for line in text_file.readlines() ]
```

Sort the list of names using either of the methods above, and then write to a new file.

Based on this comment:

> yes, but when i try to sort it comes
>   back the same. Here, if I input
>   a,c,d,b in the raw_input it comes back
>   as ['acdb']

The reason why you are unable to read the names back correctly is because you are using [writelines](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#file.writelines).

> **file.writelines(sequence)**
>
> Write a sequence of strings to the file. The sequence can be any iterable
>   object producing strings, typically a
>   list of strings. There is no return
>   value. (The name is intended to match
>   readlines(); writelines() does not add
>   line separators.)

You could either write the lines to your file as you ask for them:

```
text_file= open ("NAMES.txt", "w")

while True:
    Input = raw_input("Enter a name or press 'v' to quit:")
    if Input == "v":
        break
    text_file.write(Input)

text_file.close()
```

or you could append an endline character to your inputs:

```
Names.append(Input+"\n")
```

Since you aren't using the Names list anyways the first option allows you to forgo creating an unnecessary variable.

Comment: Thanks, I did try that before, but it returns the file unsorted.if I input a,c,d,b in the raw_input it comes back as ['acdb']?

Comment: what did you try after you got the names list?

Comment: names.sort()  I don't understand why it doesn't sort. could it be my list? there are no commas between the items.....

Comment: @ Mr. Ms yes you aren't getting your items back correctly because you are using the writelines method. see my edit

Comment: It was my list msalvadore helped me out on it. sorry, i was a little confused. Thank you though!